# How to unit test HTML being rendered from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am having a little trouble working out how to UNIT test with JEST and vanilla JS as nothign is really coming up online.

I am calling an API endpoint and then rendering that data as HTML - A set of UL/ LI's and a sub menu if there is a submenu.

How would you go about breaking this function up to unit test it - I am not even really sure where to start

Here is the data

```
   "items":[
      {
         "label":"Work",
         "url":"#/work",
         "items":[
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"About",
         "url":"#/about",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"What we do",
               "url":"#/about/what-we-do"
            },
            {
               "label":"How we work",
               "url":"#/about/how-we-work"
            },
            {
               "label":"Leadership",
               "url":"#/about/leadership"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"foo",
         "url":"#/foo",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"Client Services",
               "url":"#/foo/client"
            },
            {
               "label":"Creative",
               "url":"#/foo/creative"
            },
            {
               "label":"Motion & Media",
               "url":"#/foo/motion"
            }


         ]
      }

   ]
}
```

Here is the function I am calling to create the DOM elements - Its slightly messy but it is essentially creating the anchor tags and Ul / Li's.

```
  createNavigationMenu: function (data) {
    return data.map((item) => {
      const listElement = document.createElement('li');
      const listElementAnchor = document.createElement('a');
      const subMenuContainer = document.createElement('ul');
      const chevron = document.createElement('span');

      listElementAnchor.setAttribute("href", `${item.url}`);
      listElementAnchor.setAttribute("class", 'navigation__primary-menu-anchor');
      listElementAnchor.innerHTML = item.label;

      listElement.setAttribute("class", "navigation__primary-menu-item");
      listElement.appendChild(listElementAnchor);
      this.navigationContainer.append(listElement);

      subMenuContainer.setAttribute("class", "navigation__submenu");
      item.items.length ? listElement.append(subMenuContainer) : null
      chevron.setAttribute("class", "arrow");
      item.items.length ? listElementAnchor.append(chevron) : null

      return item.items.map(submenuItem => {
        const subMenuContainerItem = document.createElement('li');
        const subMenuContainerItemAnchor = document.createElement('a');
        subMenuContainerItemAnchor.setAttribute("href", `/${submenuItem.url}`);
        subMenuContainerItemAnchor.setAttribute("class", 'navigation__submenu-menu-anchor');
        subMenuContainerItemAnchor.innerHTML = submenuItem.label;
        subMenuContainerItem.setAttribute("class", "navigation__submenu-menu-item");

        subMenuContainerItem.append(subMenuContainerItemAnchor)
        listElement.append(subMenuContainer);
        subMenuContainer.append(subMenuContainerItem)

      })
    })
  }
```

I have tried this with JSDOM but it does not seem to work

```
const data = {
  "items": [
    {
      "label": "Work",
      "url": "#/work",
      "items": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}
const markup = `<ul id="navigation__primary-menu" class="navigation__primary-menu">
  <li>
    <h1 class="navigation__primary-logo">HUGE </h1> <span id="iconSpan" class="saved"> </span>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation__primary-list-item"></li>
  <li class="navigation__primary-menu-item"><a href="#/work" class="navigation__primary-menu-anchor">Work</a></li>
</ul>`


describe('should map data correctly', () => {
  test('markup entered', () => {
    const { windpw } = new JSDOM(markup);
    const nav = Controller.createNavigationMenu(data)
    expect(dom.serialize()).toMatch(nav)

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for guidance only. It will not 'just work.'

Your request is complex - tests are usually written in Node (which is server side) and you are talking about using document and the DOM (which is client side.)

I would suggest looking into https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom which allows you to emulate document in Node.

Then, from their docs, something like:

```
const dom = new JSDOM();
```

and update your generator like this:

```
createNavigationMenu: function (data, dom) { //pass in your dom object here
  return data.map((item) => {
    const listElement = dom.createElement('li');
    .... //replace all documents with dom
```

Pass your special dom into your generator function when running tests, and pass the true document at other times.

Finally, in your test (using jest example):

```
describe('dom test', () => {
  it('should render like this', () => {
    expect(dom.serialize()).toMatchSnapshot()
  }
}
```

As an aside, DOM manipulation is usually only necessary in this day and age if you're trying to be super clever. I strongly suggest (if you haven't considered it) trying to use a framework that is going to make your life much easier. I use React, which also comes with the added bonus of testing frameworks that allow you to test rendering. Other frameworks are available.